# how to find password for mySQL database server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I find the password for my database on phpMyAdmin? I want to connect mySQL database just by using `mysqli_connect` and understand that three strings are needed, but I can't seem to find where the password could be. If anyone could help that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Is this a new install? How did you install it? What MySQL version?

Comment: Nah, I never installed it. I just created a database name through cPanel and added columns to it on phpMyAdmin, which I also accessed through cPanel. Should I install MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some simple commands:

```
sudo su

cd /etc/mysql
cat my.cnf
```

When the file my.cnf is opened you can read it's contents, and it should contain your username and password for the current installation.

Hope this helps! ;)

Comment: ok, I'm assuming I would have to install mySQL then in order to do this. Correct?

Comment: Of course, but it shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 0):

[cPanel documentation](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/sql-services/mysql-root-password/) says the password is stored in /root/.my.cnf.

Use this user/password to create a new user for your mysql application.

Comment: where do I find /root/.my.cnf.? I just finished installing it and I'm on the mySQL workbench plugin, what's next?